# Java upload file with swt progress bar

Tags: java, file-upload, swt, progress-bar

In my **JAVA RCP** application I **UPLOAD** file to a REST API using HTTPPOST.

Now, I want my **SWT PROGRESS BAR** to connect with the upload file method and display the progress.
I've seen many post on the net and also here on stackover, but none of these post were helpful.

Could anyone help ?

Thanks in advance !

Ismail

Comment: What's the exact method you upload the file with? Is there any place where you can poll the percentage already uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Progress bar examples here http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/

Comment: Well, thanks for the link but it's not updating a progress bar as a file is uploaded.

Comment: Edit the question and add the code.You have to manually set the progress status.

Comment: There is no progress bar code yet. I'm looking for some instructions to follow so i could write the progress bar code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Jobs and Progress Monitoring](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJobs/article.html).

For example, you could start a task with a monitor's size the size of your files to upload and frequently call #worked(int).